# Python bytecode generated when multiprocessing Pool is called

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have written some Python 2.7 code where I set `sys.dont_write_bytecode = True` to prevent .pyc files from being written. I have used this many times previously without issue.

I am now working on a new program using `multiprocessing` and I noticed that bytecode is generated when `Pool` is called, regardless of the bytecode variable. Please help me to understand why.

Here is working test code:

```
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
from multiprocessing import Pool

# bytecode gets generated when Pool is included
pool = Pool(processes=2)

print 'done'
```

Comment: have you considered `python -B` or `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` envvar?

Comment: I had to look those up, but it seems the environment variable approach worked. I gather that means bytecode is always off (rather than case-by-case), but that works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is because `multiprocessing` spawns new python interpreter processes, and this flag is only meaningful inside the process where it is set. I'm also guessing that it will actually work on POSIX systems, where multiprocessing uses `fork()`, which might preserve interpreter state—it seems to be the case on my system. And, my last guess is that it might be not so easy to avoid these bytecode files, as multiprocessing runs the worker code on Windows only after importing the module, which is the moment when the bytecode files are created. But all of that is just an educated guess based on my knowledge of how the interpreter and the multiprocessing module work—please wait for some real answers.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Sounds plausible - at least you have given me some avenues to investigate further.